# NumPy: How to elegantly index an array that may be 0-dimensional?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Minimal example:

```
import numpy as np

def foo(arr):
    negative = arr < 0
    arr2 = arr + 1
    arr2[negative] *= -1
    return arr2

a = np.array([1])
b = np.array(1)
print(foo(a)) # works, also works for any other nonzero dimensional array
print(foo(b)) # TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object does not support item assignment
```

Is there an elegant way to make `foo` support both zero and nonzero dimensional arrays? I would prefer to use something 'pythonic' rather than branching based on `arr2.ndim`.

EDIT: this version of foo seems to work without the above issue, though it modifies the input. Why does this work but not the above?

```
def foo(arr):
    negative = arr < 0
    arr += 1
    arr[negative] *= -1
    return arr
```

Comment: What should the output be for `foo(b)`?

Comment: @norok2 it would be zero dimensional array with value 2.

Comment: Indexing `b` isn't the problem.   The problem arises because `b+1` is a numpy scalar, the `np.int64` type.  And it's not the indexing, but the assignment (as the error says)

Comment: What's un-pythonic about branching?  `if` is a perfectly good Python operation!  Suggestions like `atleast_1d` just hide that kind of dimension testing.  The fact that you want a scalar output complicates any solution based on increasing the dimension.

Comment: @hpaulj see the edit. For some reason the second version works but not the first. I would have liked for it to be that simple...

Comment: `arr+1` produces a new object.  `arr+=1` modifies `arr`.  Check the type in both cases.

Comment: Now this is interesting, `arr + 1` is not `WRITEABLE`, while the original `arr` is, hence the difference when assigning.

Comment: @kpjoshi check my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

What about using [`numpy.atleast1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_1d.html)?

```
def foo(arr):
    negative = arr < 0
    arr2 = np.atleast_1d(arr + 1)
    arr2[negative] *= -1
    return arr2

foo(np.array(-5))
```

output: `array([4])`

Comment: I would prefer the dimensionality of the input to be maintained. @Nin17 answer might be better.

Comment: @kpjoshi then return: `arr2.reshape(arr.shape)` ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue where `arr2 = arr + 1` is not `WRITEABLE`, while `arr` is:

```py
for x in (np.array(1), np.array(1) + 1):
    print(x.dtype, x.ndim)
    print(x.flags)
# int64 0
#   C_CONTIGUOUS : True
#   F_CONTIGUOUS : True
#   OWNDATA : True
#   WRITEABLE : True
#   ALIGNED : True
#   WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
#   UPDATEIFCOPY : False

# int64 0
#   C_CONTIGUOUS : True
#   F_CONTIGUOUS : True
#   OWNDATA : True
#   WRITEABLE : False
#   ALIGNED : True
#   WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
#   UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

This is causing the assignment expression to fail.

---

There are a number of workaround for this:

- copy the input beforehand so that you can use `+=` operator to modify a copy of input, which is still writeable

```py
def foo_cp(arr):
    arr = arr.copy()
    negative = arr < 0
    arr += 1
    arr[negative] *= -1
    return arr
```

- use branching as you originally indicated:

```py
def foo_if(arr):
    negative = arr < 0
    arr2 = arr + 1
    if negative.ndim > 0:
        arr2[negative] *= -1
    elif arr < 0:
        arr2 = -arr2
    return arr2
```

- use an equivalent algebraic expression

```
def foo_float(arr):
    return np.sign(np.sign(arr) + 0.5).astype(np.int8) * (arr + 1)
```

for integers, the above can be simplified to:

```
def foo_int(arr):
    return np.abs(arr + 1)
```

---

Below some tests to show how eventually all these work and produce the correct output for the indicated use cases:

```
funcs = foo_cp, foo_if, foo_float, foo_int, foo_atl1d, foo_updown

int_arrs = [np.arange(-20, 20), np.array([2]), np.array(2), np.array([-1]), np.array(-1), np.array(-2)]
float_arrs = [np.arange(-20, 20) / np.pi, np.array([1.2]), np.array(1.2), np.array([-0.5]), np.array(-0.5), np.array(1.2)]

int_base = [funcs[0](arr) for arr in int_arrs]
float_base = [funcs[0](arr) for arr in float_arrs]
for func in funcs:
    int_res = [func(arr) for arr in int_arrs]
    float_res = [func(arr) for arr in float_arrs]
    is_good_int = all(np.allclose(x, y) for x, y in zip(int_base, int_res))
    is_good_float = all(np.allclose(x, y) for x, y in zip(float_base, float_res))
    print(f"{func.__name__:>12} {is_good_int!s:>5} {is_good_float!s:>5} ", end="")
    %timeit -n 64 -r 4 [func(arr) for arr in int_arrs]; [func(arr) for arr in float_arrs]
#       foo_cp  True  True 64 loops, best of 4: 74.6 µs per loop
#       foo_if  True  True 64 loops, best of 4: 53.7 µs per loop
#    foo_float  True  True 64 loops, best of 4: 85.8 µs per loop
#      foo_int  True False 64 loops, best of 4: 28.4 µs per loop
#    foo_atl1d  True  True 64 loops, best of 4: 177 µs per loop
#   foo_updown  True  True 64 loops, best of 4: 115 µs per loop
```

(I have also included `foo_atl1d()` from [@mozway's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72710971/5218354) and `foo_updown()` from [@Nin17's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72711067/5218354)).

Note that while `foo_cp()` or `foo_float()` may be simpler to write, they are likely slower than `foo_if()`. On the other hand, `foo_int()` is likely the fastest. `foo_atl1d()` and `foo_updown()` seems to be the slowest after all (for the tested inputs).

Answer (score 1):

You could increase the dimensions of the array by 1, perform the operations and then reduce dimensions by 1:

```
def foo(arr):
    arr = np.array([arr])
    negative = arr < 0
    arr2 = arr + 1
    arr2[negative] *= -1
    return np.array(*arr2)
foo(np.array(-5))
```

Output:

```
array(4)
```

Comment: I suppose this will work. But it feels just about as unpythonic as using an if-else statement.